# Why the branch that I am creating on Git does not appear?

Tags: git

This is what I am doing:

```
C:\Users\username\Dropbox\myproject\androidapp\build>git branch -D master
```

error: branch 'master' not found.

```
C:\Users\username\Dropbox\myproject\androidapp\build>git checkout -b master
Switched to a new branch 'master'

C:\Users\username\Dropbox\myproject\androidapp\build>git branch

C:\Users\username\Dropbox\myproject\androidapp\build>git branch -a

C:\Users\username\Dropbox\myproject\androidapp\build>
```

I see the message: Switched to a new branch 'master'. Why is it that the new branch 'master' does not exist, when apparently I am being able to switch to the branch 'master'?

Comment: Using git inside Dropbox is usually a mistake.

Comment: I was able to not show a branch (not even master) by using an empty repo. Do you have anything there?

Comment: Why? It is just a regular folder on my local computer, but it happens to be in sync with Dropbox. Why would it even matter?

Comment: http://www.anishathalye.com/2015/08/19/git-remote-dropbox/

Comment: Oh... so you are keeping a git repo "in sync" with some dropbox stuff? You are adding a BIIIIG X to the equation.

Comment: @Edmundo, I am using "git status |more", and it says "On branch master..... Initial commit.....Changes to be committed:...... (use 'git rm --cached <file>...' to unstage)".

Comment: I did not know about issues related to using Dropbox and Git.

Comment: Is this a completely new repository? (It does look like one. The other option is the usual "Dropbox does not play well with Git" problem.)

Comment: It is a brand new repository, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed an initial commit:

```
C:\Users\myusername\Dropbox\myfolder\myproject\build>git commit -m "Initial commit."

C:\Users\myusername\Dropbox\myfolder\myproject\build>git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

C:\Users\myusername\Dropbox\myfolder\myproject\build>git branch
* master

C:\Users\myusername\Dropbox\myfolder\myproject\build>
```

Now I can see the branch "master" and everything is working correctly.

Comment: Thanks to @SLaks for the comment "You probably need to have a commit in the branch." That was the solution.

Answer (score 6):

In a completely new repository, there are no branches at all yet.

Nonethless, you are on branch `master`.  At the same time, branch `master` does not exist.

How can this be?  It's a contradictory state: in Git, a branch name identifies the *tip* commit of that branch, so a branch name *must* point to some existing commit.  But there are no commits, so `master` cannot point to any commit.

Git resolves this particular dilemma (and the related one with `git checkout --orphan newbranch`) by decreeing that you can be on a branch that does not exist.  To be on a branch, Git simply stores the name of that branch in the `HEAD` file.  Then, once you make a commit, the branch name actually springs into existence, pointing to the new commit—which is a new *root* commit, i.e., has no parent.

(This is an implementation detail and you aren't really *supposed* to depend on it, but you can peek: `cat .git/HEAD` and you will see it contains `ref: refs/heads/master`, indicating that you are on branch `master`.  This is true whether or not branch `master` exists!  The official ways to read `HEAD` like this are with `git symbolic-ref HEAD` and `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD` and `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.  All three behave in subtly different ways, so one picks which program and options to use depending on what one wants for the detached HEAD case.)

Currently, `git branch` lists only branches that actually exist.  That will probably remain true in the future, but who knows?

Comment: "there are no branches at all yet" - This can be verified by manually listing the branches with `ls .git/refs/heads`. If there were branches, there would be files named after them, and the contents of each would the checksum of the commit they point to. No files = no branches. (This is also an implementation detail and should not be relied on.)

Comment: @8bittree: one should also look for `.git/packed-refs`. I suspect a lot of this is going to change soonish, as there has been a whole bunch of work done on pluggable back-ends for storing references (presumably to allow a real database to be plugged in).

Answer (score 0):

> Switched to a **new** branch 'master'

`git checkout -b` *creates* the branch

Comment: If I only use "git checkout -b", it says "error: switch `b' requires a value". So I am using "git checkout -b master" because I want to create a new branch and give it the name 'master'.

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: When I use "git branch" or "git branch -a", it is supposed to list my branches and I was expecting to see "master" because that is the branch that I supposedly created, but I do not see any branches listed.

Comment: You probably need to have a commit in the branch.

Comment: When I try "git commit -m 'initial commit'", the error I see is: "error: pathspec 'commit'' did not match any file(s) known to git."

Comment: Wow, I was supposed to use git commit -m "initial commit" and not git commit -m 'initial commit'. I thought it was the same to use single Vs. double quote, but I can see it is not the same.

Comment: You were right, I needed to have a commit in the branch. That was the solution.