# how to Specify master branch by initialising git?

Tags: git

I typed the command from the prompt-

```
G:\new-git-project>git init
```

After that the prompt says-

```
G:\new-git-project\.git\
```

But it doesn't give indication of the master branch created.The expected result should have been-

```
(master#)G:\new-git-project\.git\
```

Where is the error?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/44035462/1256452

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone a git project first. Refer to the tutorial [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial).

```
$ git init
$ git clone https://github.com/your/repo.git # Sets master -> origin/master
$ git branch -r # shows origin/master
```

For newly created/empty repos,

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "commit message"
$ git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Mine is an empty repo. The last command given an error stating that error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

Comment: @torek The link you gave is useful but it fails to tell the reason of the error  after I pushed my first commit in an empty repository.The error is :error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

Answer (score 0):

Your command prompt is not specifying the `master` branch because you have only created your repo...**it doesn't yet have any commits for a branch to point to**.

After your `git init` you can create an initial empty commit like this:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Initial commit'
```